# Google Visualisation API Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

Good afternoon.

I'm trying to analyse some data in a Google spreadsheet useing the query language, but I've hit a brickwall and hope someone can help.

Here's the data: 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0ApL1zT2P00q5dE1tQVhLcHdiZ1hQRXBvc0tFdFV1Zmc&hl=en_GB&authkey=CISto5cD

I've created a query that allows me to create a table listing the number of crimes in a local neighbourhood in ascending order, thus

https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select C, D order by D&key=tMmAXKpwbgXPEposKEtUufg&hl=en_GB#gid=1

All I want to do is reorder the table so that the highest are listed first.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Dead simple. Just add desc to the query and results display in the opposite direction